# how to set same width to column of thead and tbody of table which generate dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set same width to column of tbody and thead.
I need `tbody` scrollable, `thead` freeze and Number of columns are not fixed...! I google a lot for same....
Some code snippets i have tried....

**First e.g**
 For `thead` and `tbody` I have set separate `div` and `table`. 
 Here i have set thead `style="display:block;"`.

```html
<div style="border:solid;border-color:red;" >
 <div style="border:solid;">
  <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead style="background-color:red;display:block">
                <tr>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Fruits</span></th>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Vitamin A</span></th>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Vitamin C</span></th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
</div>
<div style="height:80px; overflow:auto;border:solid;border-color:yellow;">
<table border="1" width="100%">

        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th>Oranges</th>
                        <td>295 ui</td>
                        <td>69.7 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Bananas</th>
                        <td>76 ui</td>
                        <td>10.3 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Apples</th>
                        <td>98 ui</td>
                        <td>8.4 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Oranges</th>
                        <td>295 ui</td>
                        <td>69.7 mg</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Second e.g** 
  Here I set same `div` and `table` for `thead` and `tbody` keeping `thead` `position:fixed`

```html
     <div style="border:solid;overflow:scroll;height:80px">
      <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead style="background-color:red;position:fixed;">
                    <tr>
                            <th>Fruits</th>
                            <th>Vitamin A</th>
                            <th>Vitamin C</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Apples</th>
                            <td>98 ui</td>
                            <td>8.4 mg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Oranges</th>
                            <td>295 ui</td>
                            <td>69.7 mg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Oranges</th>
                            <td>295 ui</td>
                            <td>69.7 mg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Bananas</th>
                            <td>76 ui</td>
                            <td>10.3 mg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Apples</th>
                            <td>98 ui</td>
                            <td>8.4 mg</td>
                    </tr>
    
            </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Anyone faced same issue...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for th and td same width:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 98%;
}
tr {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 32.6% !important;
}
span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:solid;border-color:red;" >
 <div style="border:solid;background-color: red;">
  <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead style="background-color:red;display:block">
                <tr>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Fruits Fruits Fruits Fruits Fruits Fruits Fruits Fruits</span></th>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Vitamin A Vitamin A Vitamin A Vitamin A </span></th>
                        <th style="width:40%"><span>Vitamin C Vitamin C Vitamin C Vitamin C </span></th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
</div>
<div style="height:80px; overflow:auto;border:solid;border-color:yellow;">
<table border="1" width="100%">

        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th>Oranges</th>
                        <td>295 ui</td>
                        <td>69.7 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Bananas</th>
                        <td>76 ui</td>
                        <td>10.3 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Apples</th>
                        <td>98 ui</td>
                        <td>8.4 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Oranges</th>
                        <td>295 ui</td>
                        <td>69.7 mg</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```

Comment: `tbody` must scroll if overflow

Comment: You can add span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
} in span tag.

Comment: Thanks... Its works fine for fixed number of column.... But its not working if number of column are increases or decreases......???

Comment: if you want to increase or decrease column then you need to set width.

Comment: Since record generates dynamically..... number of column are not fix..... So I need generic solution which work for `n` number of column... Thanks

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you cannot set different widths for different cells of the header :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this in style tag:

```
thead th,tbody td{
  width: 10%;//or what you want
  float:left;
}
```